# Split complex string with delimiters in Java

Tags: java, split

I have a simple XML line I want to split using `String.split()` but it does not work properly.

```
(<)position x="1" y="2" z="3" /(>) with no parentesis
```

Here is the regex I tried to apply:

```
String regex ="(<)position x=\"|\" y=\"|\" z=\"|\" /(>)";
```

The expected result is

> 1 2 3

Comment: What is your input string?  What is the expected result?  What is the result you are getting?  Please clarify.

Comment: You are getting warmer.  However, please _edit_ the question.  The comments section is for users to request clarification.  Clarifications themselves should be added as part of the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with the `split()` method.  It will only separate the string into pieces, it will not filter out individual groups.  Instead, you can use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes

```
final String input = "<position x=\"1\" y=\"2\" z=\"3\" />";
final String regex = "<position\\sx=\"([0-9]+)\"\\sy=\"([0-9]+)\"\\sz=\"([0-9]+)\"\\s\\/>";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    final String x = matcher.group(1);
    final String y = matcher.group(2);
    final String z = matcher.group(3);
    System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);
}
```

However, if you are planning on parsing XML, I would *highly* suggest using an XML parser instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. But does the [0-9] mean that it will filter only numbers from 0 to 9? x,y,z can be doubles.

Comment: @aesine Yes, but you can use `[0-9\\.]` if you want to include the decimal.  However, if you familiarize yourself with regular expressions, you could have figured this one out yourself :).  Regex is an extremely valuable tool for almost any developer, so it's worth taking the time to learn.  (It's right up there with XML parsers).